# Stop getting "install from unknown source"

Tags: windows, installation, installer

I made an installer for my Program on PC, but everytime someone has to install it it displays an "allow installations from an unknown source" popup. How could I become a "known source"?

Maybe this is an unrelated or kinda meta question, but searching for it just shows me results for how to enable unknown sources on an Android device or PC.

Comment: What installer framework are you using? What OS?

Comment: I'm using [Inno Setup Compiler](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) on Windows 10 and I don't know how to get or where can I check for digital signatures